# Configure access to View's SubFolders in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, project-structure

I am wondering if it is possible to do following with ***ASP.NET MVC 5***.

I would like to have a **OrderController** and the following folder's structure

> View/Orders/Details/

I need to know how we can configure methods for `Details` folder?

I mean **Create/Edit/List**.

Have we use some method attribute for it or routing and how it should be done?

Thanks!

**P.S.**

I found very useful this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: You mean you want to, in your action method, do this `return View("~/Views/Orders/Details/Create.cshtml");`?

Comment: So have I answered your question with that comment?

Comment: What do you mean by "configure access"?  Or "configure methods"?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you asking about authorization for action methods?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, please. I will accept it.

Comment: @David I mean if I put method `Create` into `OrderController` for `View("~/Views/Orders/Details/Create.cshtml");` have I adjust it somehow so it will be executed?

Comment: @ClarkKent: You seem to be confusing some terminology here.  Any method in a controller which returns an `ActionResult` can return any view you'd like.  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: @David. I mean I cannot to have two `Create` methods for `Order` and `Details` at the same controller. But I need to.

Comment: @ClarkKent: You can have two methods with the same name as along as they're distinct overloads of one another.  If they accept different arguments, they can both be on the same controller.  Though *semantically* that's probably not a good idea since controllers usually equate to some semantic concept and having two in the same controller could get confusing.

Comment: @David How do you suggest to resolve that? Could you provide some answer, please?

Comment: @ClarkKent: Resolve *what*?  How to have two methods with the same name in the same class?  The answer below already illustrates that, the method parameters just need to be different from each other.  Or do you mean how to put semantic concepts into their own controllers?  Just create two separate controllers.  In this case you might have an `OrdersController` and an `OrderDetailsController` if the two concepts really are different from one another.  It's difficult to be more specific without knowing your modeling and use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options. You can either make your own code to determine the correct view to return which is fairly complex or you can specify the view you need using the full path. Additionally if you have to have methods with the same (not sure why you would want that), then you would need to change your routing. An option is to use attribute routing.

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    [Route("CreateOrder")]
    public ActionResult Create(Order order)
    {
        //Snip
        return View("~/Views/Orders/Details/Create.cshtml");
    }

    [Route("CreateOrderDetails")]
    public ActionResult Create(OrderDetails orderDetails)
    {
        //Snip
        return View("~/Views/Orders/Details/Create.cshtml");
    }


}
```

Comment: David, I need to know what do I have to do with `Create` method of  `OrderController`. Will it react to that path? I mean have I use Routing or something else for that method? And how it should be done.

Comment: I see. But, David I have the method with the same name for `Order`. How to resolve it? I mean I am gonna keep at the same controller methods that have the same name but for different Views in folder's chain.

Comment: You either rename one (perhaps `OrderDetails`) or use routing which effectively does the same thing for the URL